# dns to directadmin ip-address:port

Tags: dns, subdomain, port, ip-address

Right now I have a VPS with DirectAdmin installed on it, on default DirectAdmin is reachted by going to `31.154.241.12:2222` (example ip).

I am trying to set up a dns server that will forward `da.mysite.com` to `31.154.241.12:2222`.
Sitting this up at the hosting company didn't give any errors, but when I try add this line to my DirectAdmin DNS settings it gives the following error:

Cannot Add Record - The value must be an IP address

Doing this would give my customers a better quality of usage and they feel like I provide all the services.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

A DNS server just resolves your hostname (da.mysite.com) to an IP (31.154.241.12). It knows nothing about your port number.

To achieve what you describe, you have to set up some sort of a proxy... Read up on mod_proxy in Apache if you are using it and use a RewriteRule to achieve a redirection from hostname.com:5222 to da.hostname.com, for instance.